# In League of Legends does Dorans Blade work with Pantheons Spear Shot

Tags: league-of-legends

Dorans blade has 3% lifesteal, if i am carrying it and throwing my spear (Q ability) am I getting the 3% lifesteal with every hit?

Comment: No your not getting the 3%, your spear (q) is a spell that does AD dmg, but it's still a spell, and would benefit off of spell vamp, not lifesteal. See linked question in comment above.

Comment: It could've worked if in the Spear Shot description figured "applies on-hit effects", but it doesn't.

Comment: dont start dorans on pantheon :) start with machete in jungle and flask in toplane.